# Error in compiling XML:Xerces-2.7.0

Tags: perl-module

I compiled xerces-c-2.7.0 and ran perl Makefile.PL in the XML-Xerces-2.7.0 directory

Comiple XML:Xerces using gmake and gor below error:

```
> Blockquote

<br>make[1]: Entering directory `/home/czhang/XML_Xerces-2.7.0/Handler'</br>
<br>make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/czhang/XML_Xerces-2.7.0/Handler'</br>
<br>g++ -c  -I. -IHandler -I/home/czhang/xerces-c-src_2_7_0/include -w -DNDEBUG </br><br>-DXML_USE_NATIVE_TRANSCODER -DXML_USE_INMEM_MESSAGELOADER -DXML_USE_PTHREADS <br>-DXML_USE_NETACCESSOR_SOCKET -D_REENTRANT -DDEBIAN -D_GNU_SOURCE -O   <br>-DVERSION=\"2.7.0-0\" -DXS_VERSION=\"2.7.0-0\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib/perl5/5.14.2/i586-linux-thread-multi/CORE"   Xerces.cpp </br>

<br>Xerces.cpp:1219:9: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant</br>
<br>Xerces.cpp:1220:9: error: ‘SwigPerlWrapper’ does not name a type</br>
<br>Xerces.cpp:1225:3: error: ‘SwigPerlWrapperPtr’ does not name a type</br>
<br>Xerces.cpp:69331:1: error: too many initializers for ‘swig_command_info’</br>
<br>Xerces.cpp:69331:1: error: too many initializers for ‘swig_command_info’</br>
<br>Xerces.cpp:69331:1: error: too many initializers for ‘swig_command_info’</br>
<br>Xerces.cpp:69331:1: error: too many initializers for ‘swig_command_info’</br>
<br>Xerces.cpp:69331:1: error: too many initializers for ‘swig_command_info’</br>
<br>Xerces.cpp:69331:1: error: too many initializers for ‘swig_command_info’</br>
<br>Xerces.cpp:69331:1: error: too many initializers for ‘swig_command_info’</br>
<br>Xerces.cpp: In function ‘void boot_XML__Xerces(PerlInterpreter*, CV*)’:</br>
<br>Xerces.cpp:69557:5: error: ‘struct swig_command_info’ has no member named ‘wrapper’
<br>gmake: *** [Xerces.o] Error 1</br>

> Blockquote
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to re-build the swig bindings when building the Xerces perl module in order to build the module with perl 5.8.9 or later.

To do that, make sure you have swig installed (build from source or install the package for your system) and set the XERCES_DEVEL environment variable to 1. If you are using bash:

```
export XERCES_DEVEL=1
```

Then do the usual:

```
perl Makefile.PL
make 
make install
```

When you run make it will use swig to regenerate the bindings and you'll be all set.

Comment: Is it safe to assume the `XML::Xerces` has died at version 2.7.0?